# JSSOR, how to fit image to parent div size

Tags: jquery, jssor

I found, a splendid jquery plugin to rotate banner.
All script i keep in div

```
<div style="background-color:black; width:70%; height:300px;" class="adv">.
```

Maybe, sb knows, how to fit image to above div.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 1):

Please place the slider in a container like you stated above, and then you can scale the slider to width of the container.

```
<div style="background-color:black; width:70%;" class="adv">
    <div id="slider1_container" ...>
        ...
    </div>
</div>


    <script>
        ...
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);

        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        ////responsive code end

    </script>
```